# Why is Chrome showing a white curtain on top of SVG?

Tags: android, google-chrome, svg

On Chrome 61 on Android, Chrome sometimes shows a white curtain on top of an SVG image. I do have reports it also happens on Chrome Desktop, but I couldn't find a way to show it yet.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body >
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Booking.com_logo.svg">
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's a live example](https://kkdevs.com/svgtest.html). Stackoverflow won't let me upload an QR-Image, so here's the URL for your mobile: http://kkdevs.com/svgtest.html

The screenshot shows that page:
[image]

Why are the first two images overlayed by something? How can I remove the curtain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug in Chrome 61.  It seems to have been found and fixed, because it isn't in Chrome Canary (63). Though I haven't been able to find the bug number.